# Exclude module dependencies from jar file in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

So i have included a local jar as a dependency using following command in gradle - 
"compile files("${PathToJar}/name.jar") 
Now i want to exclude some module from above jar just like we do with normal dependencies exclusion

```
compile('com.a.b:' + version) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.inject', module: 'guice_servlet'
        exclude group: 'com.google.inject', module: 'guice'
        exclude group: 'io.dropwizard'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
        exclude group: 'log4j'
    }
```

I googled a lot but could not find a proper command.

Comment: I am not following. You want to exclude "module" from a local JAR. How would Gradle know to include transitive dependencies of a local JAR?

Comment: I created a uber jar from my another project and included as a library in my current project. Now from that uber jar, i want to exclude some of the modules.and as far as i know uber jar include all the transitive dependencies, isn't it ?

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to achieve is not directly possible in Gradle.

**[ModuleDependency.exclude(Map)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleDependency.html#exclude(java.util.Map)) is used for excluding transitive dependencies.** That means if dependency depends on another dependency (JAR), Gradle effectively creates dependency tree. By using `exclude()` method you can remove dependencies from the tree.

However if you have an UberJar, dependencies (classes) are bundled in the JAR itself. So **you cannot use `exclude()` for excluding classes from a JAR itself**, it can be only used for excluding JARs from the tree.